# Create a query or view that will split a colum into two based on a condition

Tags: sql, split

I have a table that I want to use as a master table on my database, which will get updated with data every quarter. Each quarter each brand will have their figures updated with new rows of information along with a column of data that will show what quarter and year that data is looking at. So an example of the data set would be:

```
Brand | Share | Quarter | Year

Jonas |  2.4  |   4     |  2012

Smith |  3.6  |   4     |  2012

Dexes |  1.3  |   4     |  2012

Jonas |  3.0  |   1     |  2013

Smith |  1.1  |   1     |  2013

Dexes |  2.0  |   1     |  2013

Jonas |  1.1  |   2     |  2013

Smith |  4.0  |   2     |  2013

Dexes |  3.2  |   2     |  2013
```

What I want to create is a query that will show the table as follows:

```
Brand | Q4 12 | Q1 13 | Q2 13

Jonas | 2.4 | 3.0 | 1.1

Smith | 3.6 | 1.1 | 4.0

Dexes | 1.3 | 2.0 | 3.2
```

So the Share column is split using the quarter and year to split it. I can create a basic select query and join tables, but I wouldn't know how to start with splitting a column within the same table. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you can use pivot table operator for this as:

```
create table table1 (Brand varchar(20), Share decimal(10,2), [Quarter] int, [Year] int);

insert into table1 values 
('Jonas', 2.4, 4, 2012),
('Smith', 3.6, 4, 2012),
('Dexes', 1.3, 4, 2012),
('Jonas', 3.0, 1, 2013),
('Smith', 1.1, 1, 2013),
('Dexes', 2.0, 1, 2013),
('Jonas', 1.1, 2, 2013),
('Smith', 4.0, 2, 2013),
('Dexes', 3.2, 2, 2013)

select * 
from 
(select brand,Share,'Q' + cast([Quarter]as varchar(1)) +'-'+ cast([Year] as varchar(4)) as QuarterYear
from table1)D
Pivot (sum (share)
       for QuarterYear
       in ([Q4-2012],[Q1-2013],[Q2-2013]))T;
```

Dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)      
       ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = N'';
--Get column names for entire pivoting
SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(QuarterYear)
  FROM (select distinct 'Q' + cast([Quarter]as varchar(1)) +'-'+ cast([Year] as varchar(4)) as QuarterYear 
        from table1
       ) AS T;  
PRINT @columns;

SET @sql = N' SELECT brand, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(select brand,Share,''Q'' + cast([Quarter]as varchar(1)) +''-''+ cast([Year] as varchar(4)) as QuarterYear
from table1 ) as D
PIVOT
(
  sum (share)
  for QuarterYear IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', [', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + '))T
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Deepshikha.

I'm getting the following error though:

Unexpected token: [ in statement [(select Brand, Share, 'Q' + cast(]

Comment: Above query is in T-SQL that is for MS SQL. Are you using the same?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm using RazorSQL with SQL.
Sorry if that's not much help.